# How does arrayList.remove() function

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to figure out how does that method works, because i would like to make my own. So I came to this point:

```
public static deleteMe(int index){
 for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size;i++){
     if(i==index){
          // how to tell java to delete that member of list on the index i, 
          // but not to be arrayList.remove()
         }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Are you asking how to remove an element from `java.util.ArrayList` without calling `remove()` or how to implement remove(index) is some custom `ArrayList` like class you are implementing?

Comment: `public static deleteMe(int index)` this isn't even valid syntax... >_>

Comment: how to remove an element without calling remove() method.Thanks in advantage for your help

Comment: @javaprogrammewannabe you generally don't. You could bypass the interface with reflection, but other than that, no. Why do you assume you would be able to?

Comment: if you want to understand how it works, take a look at its source code.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The purpose of the remove method is to remove the element at that position. Suppose we have [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] and call remove(1) on it, we then have [1, 3, 4, 5]. If you want to see the source it is here http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java#l504

Comment: You could iterate to the `i`'th element with an iterator, and call `Iterator`'s remove, but that's cheating, since `Iterator's remove will call `ArrayList`'s `remove` for you.

Comment: @javaprogrammewannabe you can look at its source, here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.remove%28int%29

Comment: @eis ... because on my uni i have some assignment to implement methods and now i came to the  point where i need to implement method without using java method remove()  to delete one element of arraylist.

Comment: @javaprogrammewannabe I think you've misunderstood the assignment

Comment: @eis , ok,thanks for the help

Comment: You can't actually replicate the functionality of `remove()` on an `ArrayList`  because you'd need access to internal state which `ArrayList`, quite rightly, keeps private from meddling outsiders such as you and me.

Comment: .@Chandler Bing i will try something with this source code.

Comment: @javaprogrammewannabe I guess the assignment would be to implement the remove functioanilty using an array. similar to that in ArrayList remove method. Verify from the teacher.

Comment: Just guessing, could it be that the assignment is to implement without using Java’s standard `ArrayList` class at all (not only without using its `remove` method)?

Comment: @javaprogrammewannabe you probably should have added your existing custom list class in order to provide the necessary information for others to answer this question.

Answer (score 2):

ArrayList is based internally on a simple array, so when you delete by index you simply move everything that has higher index than the removed element one place down, look at te JDK implementation:

```java
public E remove(int index) {
  rangeCheck(index);

  modCount++;
  E oldValue = elementData(index);

  int numMoved = size - index - 1;
  if (numMoved > 0)
  System.arraycopy(elementData, index+1, elementData, index,
                             numMoved);
  elementData[--size] = null; // clear to let GC do its work

  return oldValue;
}
```

Ofcourse the inner array (elementData) is package-access so you don't have access to it, that's the whole point. If you are implementing your own list I suggest extending the `AbstractList`. If you are not then this question doesn't make sense, like I said, that's the whole point of `ArrayList` to encapsulate the inner array so you can operate on it only through methods available to you.

If you want to delete not by index, but by passing some instance of type that the `ArrayList` is holding, that requires the `equals` check, so that type needs to properly override `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

Comment: note that the implementation you quote is from old version of java, nowadays it is a bit different. It doesn't change your point however which I agree with.

Comment: Yes i am implementing my own list. which should be modified with my own method that will delete some element which i would put in parameter. deleteMe(0)-for example..Thanks.

Comment: @javaprogrammewannabe on other comment you said you need to "remove from arraylist without using delete", now you say you're implementing your own list. Those are totally distinct things. Latter makes more sense, so that's probably what you're really doing.